# Resetting origins with animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

[image]Just a quick one - I've created an array of objects by transforming instances of a mesh along the x axis but need to reset the origin of each object back to the grid centre.

How can I do this?  I can't see a node that supports that kind of reset.  I'd need to embed it in the subprogram so that each instance would be reset as it's created.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you are trying to rotate/scale around the origin, you can use Matrix nodes to rotate around a different point.

Comment: Well i generally have a hell of a time with origins which always seem to be solved by 'applying' location/rotation/scale after moves.  In this particular situation, i'm developing a form of Zack Hixon's tile flipping animation that creates an array of tiles on a generated mesh of vertices, a tile centred on each vertex.  I just know it will all go to hell once i try to apply the tiles becuase the mesh array has offset centres.  The screenshot below shows what i mean.  Thanks for your help (not sure i'd know where to start with matrix nodes to cause rotation).

Comment: You probably don't need this, there is a better method for whatever you are trying to do. You can may be try to ask that in a question directly.
In case you just want to know, this can be done by transforming the mesh data instead of transforming the objects, easy as that.

Comment: Thanks Omar but surely that only transforms vertex, edge and polygon data and not the object origin?